# How to turn location ON on a Windows 10 device with Store Blocked

Tags: windows-10, geolocation

I have a windows 10 developer VM on Azure with MS Store locked by GPO. So, there is no Maps app. I have the location service turned on in Settings and Geolocation service running in service.msc. An app I am trying to use still comes up with a message that GPS service has failed.

What can I do to simulate a fake location. I checked online, but most solutions are to install apps from the Store, I cannot do that as Store is inaccessible.

Also I have tried fakeGPS apps like GPS links and I cannot use JulianKay's app that requires the machine to run in Test mode.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have a GPO that is to blame?

Comment: Did you turn Location in Privacy settings? I don’t think this depends on the Store

Comment: There is a GPO, but I would like to go around it. The location for the the app is ON and so are the locations settings in the privacy settings.